Retriving overwritten/replaced files
After replacing same named files in a folder, how can I retrive the old files in linux ubuntu.i was moving my files from an external storage and some of my exixting files had same names and accidently I clicked overwritten. I need to recover it.Anyone help with it.

mv will, by default, overwrite duplicate files.
If you want to be warned or prompted before overwriting duplicates, use the -i flag.
You can try these steps  if you want to attempt to recover overwritten files.
